# Add scratches to a material in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, shaders

Is there a way to add scratches (like on worn metal) to a shader in Cycles?

Comment: Mix a diffuse shader, to the rest of the node tree, based on a texture; It really depends on your material, though

Comment: Use a scratch texture in the normal of a diffuse shader, or the displacement of an output shader . . .

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The *simplest* way is to use a box-mapped scratch texture to control the roughness of a glossy shader:

[image]