# How can I make this metal material look more realistic?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

I am new to Blender and I want to make this metal look more realistic.  I am using a PBR method but the handle on this sword looks like it is missing something.  Any tips would be appreciated.

[image: render of swords]

Let me know if you would like the .blender file or a screenshot of the nodes.

Comment: yes a screen shot of your nodes would probably help.

Comment: You need a wrap around the handle, you don't normally use a metal handled knife or sword. Reflective metal needs something to reflect, otherwise it looks more like plastic.

Comment: This is a tutorial on how to make a completely physically-accurate metal shader in Cycles. It should help: https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/making-realistic-pbr-materials-part-2-metal

Comment: Also related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21283/add-scratches-to-a-material-in-cycles