# How to add imperfections to the Principled BSDF Shader (Cycles)?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor, pbr

I am looking to create scratches, swipes, brushes, similar to the reference image provided, that will **only** appear where I wish them to (as shown below).

[image]

**What is the best Node Group/Layout/Structure/Workflow to implement such scratches/brushes (purely) on top of a material?**

For clarity, I have provided the reference image below, as well as the blend file, with the texture in the node setup.
http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=47820

*I also dispose of materials from Poliigon, if that is of assistance.*

[image]

Comment: The scratches and other surface detail should affect the roughness, especially given that the effect would 'reveal' the metalness of the material. Looking at the Principled Shader from 2.79, I would create a black and white map fo scratch/scrapes and then mix it with the color input for the metal but also plug it into the bump and the roughness. In the older setups, I used to use an image of scratches as a stencil between two shaders, revealing the shiny metal underneath inside the scratches.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, however I just thought you should know that the new Principled Shader (Introduced in 2.79) can do PBR metallic and dielectric materials, making BlenderGuru's PBR nodegroups obselete. [Check out this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4H5W6C_Mbck)

Comment: BlenderGuru has just posted a brief introduction to the principled shader on YouTube that should be useful to anyone who uses his PBR shader now.

Comment: Thank you, everyone! I have adapted to the Principled BSDF shader and will now use it. Could you assist me in adding imperfections to said BSDF shader? Would metalness or roughness (or even both) be used?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21283/add-scratches-to-a-material-in-cycles

Answer (score 1):

Just add mix rgb (screen) node to your roughnes map and connect surface imperfection map to the second socket