# How can I make scratches in paint so that they reveal the metal underneath?

Tags: texturing

I have a metal water bottle coated in green paint.
I am using an overlay to add scratches. I have colour and normal maps.
However, this just adds white scratches.
[image]

I want to make the scratches reveal shiny metal underneath, as if the scratch removed the paint.
Is there some way I can use these maps to indicate metalness?
Or can I use it to mix between a metal and paint texture?
Thank you.

Comment: Don't add values of textures to each other. It won't give realistic result. If you want scratches on metal, it means you want some dielectric or paint material everywhere where scratches are absent and metal where they are present - this is done with masking certain materials, in your case with scratches texture. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32166/adding-surface-scratches/32206 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21283/add-scratches-to-a-material-in-cycles for some (different ways) examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the texture as a mix factor between two different shaders.

[image]

The rest is just adjusting the lighting.

Answer (score 0):

See alternatively my video https://youtu.be/-v-t_3oQzcs which shows how to create a texture that has metal showing thru paint work where scratched.

This is a slightly dated way of working but, it works - you can also use masking ID and PBR nodes and paint in Blender itself but, it is more complex and cannot be explained here. I will be releasing a video on it (or a series) sometime over next month.

[image]

Basic process (more detail in video) If you make a texture in photoshop or gimp (taking a UV export from Blender) make a base layer of a metal texture that you want the look of to show thru as the scratches. Make sure if any grain in metal is appropriate to scale of model. Then create a 'paint' layer over the top and using a brush eraser paint away the areas that you want to show thru as scratches. Save as png and add that to your texture image node in Blender.

Comment: Please take the time to write a short summary or outline the principles used and make the answer stand on its own using links as supporting material. LInk only answers have the problem that if the link changes or disappears, then the answer will no longer be useful for other users