# shader painting!

Tags: materials

I was wondering if I made a metal material and then made a metal scratch material instead of just placing one onto of the other could I some how paint the scratches on there?
so to put it simply how do I paint an already made material onto another material?

Comment: You can use a mix shader and paint a black and white mask and use it as "Fac".

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101771/how-can-i-make-scratches-in-paint-so-that-they-reveal-the-metal-underneath